# unable to pause bash file from closing after entering into sqlplus command line

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, shell, automation

I am creating an executable to basically do a data guard task
I execute that file from another executable  with code

```
putty.exe -ssh servername  -l usernsme -pw password -m C:/auotomation/dgmgrl.sh
```

and the code in the file is

```
entdexport ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/NonValidated
export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=servername
export ORACLE_SID=ERIPRD
export PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/NonValidated/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt- 
3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/oracle/bin

dgmgrl -echo << END
connect /;
show configuration 
show database ERIPRD
exit
$SHELL
```

I have tried adding >> at the end
I can pause my file by adding $SHELL but when inside dgmgrl or sqlplus I am unable to do that.

Comment: Your *here-document* is missing the closing `END`, and instead of `$SHELL` try `bash -l`.

Comment: Your [here document](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) is missing its ending *word*, which in your case is `END`.

Answer (score 0):

Without any means of testing it (I neither have a windows machine nor an oracle server) - try this:

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/NonValidated
export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=servername
export ORACLE_SID=ERIPRD
export PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/NonValidated/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt- 
3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/oracle/bin

dgmgrl -echo << END
connect /;
show configuration 
show database ERIPRD
exit
END
bash -l
```

I assume that the **exit** is meant to be interpreted by `dgmgrl`, not the shell?

Comment: nope its still closing I copy pasted this  I added $SHELL after bash -l and it working